# How can I make my flame detector more reliable?

Tags: gas, stove

I have a new 4-ring gas hob ([GHG612BL](https://smile.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B07NM62S1Z) by SIA) and one of the features it has is flame-failure detectors (FFD) which shut off the gas to any ring if the flame goes out.  I thought that would be a prudent thing to have.

Most of these are reliable, but the largest ring often requires holding down the igniter for several seconds after it is alight (and if released too early and the flame goes out, then it may require constant ignition for up to half a minute before it is stable).  The ambient temperature doesn't seem to make a difference (it was about 15°C when installed in autumn; now it's around 3°C, but no discernable change in this behaviour).

What principle does a FFD operate on?  I'm guessing it's either thermal or triggered by either fuel or combustion gases.  Is there anything I can do to make the detector more reliable?

If it makes a difference, my fuel is bottled butane.

Comment: Considering that this is a new unit, perhaps you might contact the dealer or manufacturer for assistance under warranty.  This does not sound like normal behavior.

Comment: What make and model is said hob?

Comment: Manufacturer SIA, model GHG612BL (60cm Black 4 Burner Gas On Glass Hob With Enamel Pan Stands & FFD).

Comment: @jwh20, I thought about warranty, but didn't want to pay my a registered installer to come again if it's a simple issue that's just down to usage.  And it's only an irritation rather than a real problem: it's only the one ring and not every time.  Once it's going, there's no problem.  That's why I came here first, to find if its performance can be improved without all the palaver of an RMA.

Comment: *hob*, British, "a cooking appliance, or the flat top part of a stove, with hotplates or burners."

Answer (score 2):

Another term you could search is "flame proving sensor." This is the term we often use for the sensors in gas-fueled furnaces in the US.

Having only looked at the photos of your device, I'm guessing that its flame failure system may operate on the principle called "[flame rectification](https://www.hvacknowitall.com/blogs/blog/176063-why-flame-rod-failures-happen-and-how-to-prevent-them)." In a nutshell, the flame allows a DC current of a few microamps to flow from the sensing rod, through the flame, to the burner. The technique depends on clean surfaces on the sensing rod and the burner; combustion of contaminated air can cause an invisible electrically insulating coating to form on either surface. It is easily corrected by cleaning the surfaces with a gentle abrasive.

My best guess is that ignition is achieved by causing a spark to jump from the little metal post to the burner ring. After the ignition spark is finished maybe the post then serves as the sensing electrode.

I'd suggest ensuring the metal surfaces of the burner ring and whatever it sits on are clean and that they seat together well. Also clean the spark igniter post. If it's easy to do, remove some covers and confirm wires and other parts are connected snugly.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer exactly, but more than just a little comment...

When I redid my kitchen and switched from electric to gas, I found that with Kitchenaid the mid-range cooktop just tries to reignite (click, click, click) but that the top-of-the-line cooktop actually shuts off the gas. I did **not** get the top-of-the-line because of that (well, also save a few $). In particular, the ones with auto-shutoff often (definitely in the case of the Kitchenaid) **will not work without electricity**. That means you lose one of the advantages of a gas cooktop - the ability to use it even if the electricity is out. While we don't have frequent outages here, there have been severe weather situations (e.g., hurricane) resulting in extended outages. Being able to cook in those situations is very helpful.

Comment: That would be a real problem (power here is fairly reliable, but we get a handful of interruptions per year - the last major one was for over ½ day due to wildfire, but often just a few minutes; a 2-hour backup keeps my server uptimes to years rather than months).  Anyway, I just tried switching off the power, and pleased to say it didn't cut out.  And I confirmed that lighting (with a match) works without electric.  Now I just need to reset the oven clock (on the same circuit).

Comment: I'm glad to hear you are able to light it even without power. That is the key from my perspective. I know the top-of-the-line Kitchenaid 20 years ago definitely did **not** light (i.e., gas would not flow) without electricity - now I'm curious as to whether the latest equivalent top-of-the-line model (I replaced mine a few years ago but for the same "middle quality") has the same "feature" or not. I put in a UPS for my main system several years ago when power outages were mostly small but quite frequent. Electric utility replaced basically every wire in the neighborhood and few outages since.